# Prove that a point it's a branch point

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-points

I'm having doubts about how to approach this problem.

I have a function $f(z)= \sqrt{z^2-1}$, where the argument of the complex inside the square root it's $\arg{(z^2-1)}=\arg{(z-1)}+\arg{(z+1)}$ and will be multivaluated according to the choice of each argument for $z-1$ and $z+1$.

How can I demonstrate that $z=\pm 1$ are branch points to $f(z)$?

All the examples in books I've found already assume $z=1$ or $z=-1$ are branch points.

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: What is the definition of a branch point? Always start with a definition.

Comment: The only definition I have is: "A branch point is a point common to all possible branches of a multivalued function".

Comment: So why is $0$ the branch point of $\sqrt z$? (I assume you understand the definition you just gave us.) Then why is $1$ the branch point of $\sqrt{z-1}$?

Comment: I understand that if the square root is zero at a given point, it will be also null on the other branch, so that point will be a branch point. My problem is I don't know how to begin a formal proof with this concept.

Comment: Now you have to understand the definition of *branch* of a multivalued function.